# Is there a way to set a default value for a named parameter across many function calls in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to set a default value for a named parameter across many function calls in PowerShell?

For example if I have the following code:

```
$ComputerName = "ComputerName"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {hostname}
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ComputerName -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
Get-Process -ComputerName $ComputerName
Get-Service -ComputerName $ComputerName
```

Instead of specifying `-ComputerName` for every command I want to set it once and have each command use the value I specified.

One way to do this would be splatting:

```
$ComputerNameParameter = @{ComputerName = $ComputerName }
Invoke-Command @ComputerNameParameter -ScriptBlock {hostname}
Get-WmiObject @ComputerNameParameter -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
Get-Process @ComputerNameParameter
Get-Service @ComputerNameParameter
```

This isn't much better than the original.

I really want to be able to set a default so that while my default value is set all functions I call that have a -ComputerName parameter will use my default value unless I specify otherwise.

The End result would look something like this:

```
Set-DefaultValueForFunctionNamedParameter -Name ComputerName -Value $ComputerName
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {hostname}
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
Get-Process
Get-Service
```

Does something like this exist in PowerShell?

Comment: `$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:ComputerName']=$ComputerName`

Comment: Personally, I'd stick with splatting like:
Invoke-Command @params -ScriptBlock {hostname}
to make your code readable, intentional, and easily understood and easy to debug.  When/if you refactor your code, move things into functions or other modules, it would seem this approach would get out of hand quickly, especially if multiple defaults were being used.

Comment: @KoryGill I typically advocate the use of `$PSDefaultParameterValues` in places where function authors tend to want to supply defaults that are specific to the environment they're designing for. I prefer this approach because it keeps the function logic separate from the situations where it will be used. I think this is more readable, in that functions have a specific purpose, and are separated into modules. Your "task" script then becomes rather clean: import the module, set your defaults, implement the logic that ties together the functions (without cluttering each call with `-cn MyComp`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$PSDefaultParameterValues` (PowerShell 3.0 and later):

> The $PSDefaultParameterValues preference variable lets you specify
>   custom default values for any cmdlet or advanced function. Cmdlets and
>   functions use the custom default value unless you specify another
>   value in the command.
>
> [about_Parameters_Default_Values](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847819.aspx)

Since the Hashtable `$PSDefaultParameterValues` exists by default, you don't need to set it explicity. That is, could can just add a new Key-Value pair, so both the following work:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{"*:ComputerName" = $ComputerName}

$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:ComputerName'] = $ComputerName
```

For those who don't want to read the document, the syntax of the keys in this hashtable is: `<cmdlet>:<parameter>`.

In the example here, cmdlet is set to '*' to set the default value for all cmdlets.

Answer (score 2):

From the list of similar questions I saw people talking about using $PSDefaultParameterValues which is explained in [about_Parameters_Default_Values](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847819.aspx).

Here is how it could be used to solve my example:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{"*:ComputerName" = $ComputerName}
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {hostname}
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
Get-Process
Get-Service
```